ChromaDB failed to get results with multiple ids
I am facing a issue with ChromaDB. I am trying to get results from multiple Ids in a collection.
Example Code:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional
import newVector

app = FastAPI()

class Xitems(BaseModel):
    items: List[str]
    
@app.post("/searchi")
async def searchi(xItems: Xitems):
    items = xItems.items

    try:
        query = ' '.join(items)
        results = newVector.searchCollection('ingredients', query, 10)

        collection_direction = newVector.getCollection('directions')
        collection_titles = newVector.getCollection('title')

        directions = collection_direction.get(ids=results['ids'][0])
        titles = collection_titles.get(ids=results['ids'][0])
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

    return {"ingredients": str(results), "directions": str(directions), "titles": str(titles)}


I get the Error that its not accepting the list only strings and to convert the list into a string don't make it. with the list i get this error:
Invoke-WebRequest : {"detail":"An error occurred: Expected ID to be a str, got
['911b8613-ee7e-4f5c-8dd8-987da61ed6c3', '8c486e26-2ebe-4ff3-8e56-81bf32e4cabe',
'345a7873-18e3-487b-9744-a49d65b879ec', '0f3b9bb8-3bb5-42c0-bbdd-a14e16a6797e',
'eda8f7e9-2f3b-4bd7-ac75-135147e1915d', 'f7351e82-9968-49cf-aed3-eeef0f3ca7ed',
'37ef1795-8f3f-4903-9c7b-c086e5aca787', '9830b1bc-7a4c-48d8-b3b6-cb47a82dc5cc',
'66cb637a-3e2d-424a-ae91-f2775839b2cc', 'c2246f77-bd8b-4c68-bff6-7272e8819f8d']"}

all good and so but what exactly are they expecting with OneOrMany Parameter on the collection.get() method?
    def get(
        self,
        ids: Optional[OneOrMany[ID]] = None,
        where: Optional[Where] = None,
        limit: Optional[int] = None,
        offset: Optional[int] = None,
        where_document: Optional[WhereDocument] = None,
        include: Include = ["metadatas", "documents"],
    ) -> GetResult:


OneOrMany = Union[T, List[T]]

I don't get smart with this one can someone help how to work with list in this case?
like above described
